# Movement in Java games without pathfinding

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, 2d-games

Let's say I want to have an object move along a set path between points A, B, and C repeatedly throughout a game, based on a variable of which point it should be at/moving towards. Now, I could program in full A* pathfinding, but that would take a lot of time and require a lot of code for something that really wouldn't be used to its full worth. Is there a more efficient way to do this? At the moment, the only idea I have is to have the object move a set number of pixels in one direction, then another, then another, but it would be very easy for the object to get several pixels off after a while. I should add that none of the points are withine line-of-sight of one another, so the object will have to move around walls. Any help is appreciated, as I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

I should clarify that the walls will not be changing position. They will remain where they are for the entire game.

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem a bit more. I gather you want to work out a set path between the points which includes finding a way around obstacles but you don't want to use a pathfinding algorithm. Is that right?

Comment: In essence, yes. More specifically, how can I define a set of points to move between?

Comment: @user2925591 Would you be so kind as to upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from your comment "it would be very easy for the object to get several pixels off after a while" that the key question you have is how to regularly update the position of an object so that it follows a path between two points. If you just update it by the same amount each time then, as you say, it's not likely to end up at the end point.

The easiest way to do this is to use a variable that represents how far along the path the object has travelled so far. The algorithm can very quickly recalculate the correct position.

For example:

```
class Position {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Position interpolatedPosition(Position from, Position to, float progress) {
        return new Position(
            from.x + Math.round(progress * (to.x - from.x)), 
            from.y + Math.round(progress * (to.y - from.y)));
    }
}
```

You can fairly easily extend this to allow for constant speed by dividing `progress` by distance in the call. Or you can support movement along a path by creating a class with a list of positions and stored progress.

```
class Path {
    private final List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private float progress = 0.0f;
    private float speed = 0.1f;

    public void addPosition(Position position) {
        positions.add(position);
    }

    public void update() {
        progress += speed;
        while (progress > 1.0f) {
            currentPosition = nextPosition();
            progress -= 1.0f;
        }
    }

    public Position getCurrentPosition() {
        return Position.interpolatedPosition(positions.get(currentPosition), positions.get(nextPosition()), progress);
    }

    private int nextPosition() {
        return (currentPosition + 1) % positions.size();
    }

}
```

The second part of your question is how to determine this path ahead of time around sets of obstacles. The answer to this depends on lots of factors - particularly how optimal you want the solution to be and how efficient the search algorithm needs to be. There aren't any easy shortcuts however - generic path finding is not a simple area. Depending on your application the simplest solution may be to just define the paths yourself if you already know the layout of the map.

Comment: Again, there will be no search algorithm. Just a series of points and movement between them. Michael Laszlo's solution is the best one here as it pointed out the very obvious thing I was missing. Simply defining points and moving between them.

Answer (score 3):

I would do a full A* path finding only once and store the result object movement. Path finding can be triggered again if any other object can potentially change the path.

Comment: The question was how to define paths without implementing full pathfinding. I do not have the time to program something that would be essentially unused.

Answer (score 1):

Define a sequence of points `p` such that:

- There is no obstacle between any two consecutive points `p[i]` and `p[i + 1]`.
- Traveling along the sequence of points will take you from A to B and then to C.

In other words, you're taking a path from A to B to C and breaking it up into straight segments. The points are fixed, so you won't stray from the path due to floating-point precision.

Now you can accomplish your objective by moving the object from point to point in the sequence `p`. To move in reverse, iterate over `p` backward.

Comment: out of curiosity: defining a sequence of points... isn't that like performing a path finding? (you do it manually, but finally it's the same)...